# Spring @Autowired field is null?

Tags: java, spring

Why I am getting Spring @Autowired field as null :

```
Exception : 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.elastic.controller.MainController.getUsers(MainController.java:38)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

---

MainController.java

```
package com.elastic.controller;

        @Component()
        @Path("/user")
        public class MainController {


            @Autowired
            private ElasticSearchRepository elasticSearchRepository;

            @GET
            @Path("/getAllUsers")
            @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            public Response getUsers() throws Exception{

                List<User> userlist =new ArrayList<User>();
                Iterator<User> users = elasticSearchRepository.getAllUsers();

                while (users.hasNext()) {
                    userlist.add(users.next());
                }       

                return Response.ok(userlist).build();

            }

        }
```

---

ElasticSearchRepository.java

```
package com.elastic.repository;
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.elastic.repository")
public class ElasticSearchRepository {

public Iterator<User> getAllUsers() {
    Iterator<User> users = userRepository.findAll().iterator();
    return users;
}

}
```

---

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"      
                   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                   xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch-1.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">



                <context:annotation-config />

                <mvc:annotation-driven />
                <context:component-scan base-package="com.elastic" />
                <elasticsearch:repositories base-package="com.elastic.repository" />
                <elasticsearch:repositories base-package="com.elastic.entity" />


            </beans>
```

for Controller i have kept @component Annotation and for repository i have kept  @Configuration but still getting this exception . Pls help on this .

Comment: This isn't a Spring controller, it's a Jersey controller. Use Spring MVC or the Spring-Jersey integration.

Comment: how to do that any help ?

Comment: repository should get `@Repository` annotation

Comment: Configuration  
public class ElasticSearchRepository {            replaced with                                                                                 @Repository    but still same Issue .

Comment: and configuration should be in its own class :)

Comment: @Apostolos , Could u pls be little more clear by posting answer . I am not getting you sorry .

Comment: Your controller isn't spring managed, it is a Jersey managed instance and that will not receive injections from Spring. Setup Jersey and Spring correctly to fix it.

Comment: posting the answer, means that i have verified that this works for you and i'm not so familiar with elastic search. but in general, in a spring application, you define a configurationClass e.g. GlobalConfiguration or whatever name you want, you annotate it with `@Configuration` and/or similar annotations. Look for example here http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/gradle-spring-4-mvc-hello-world-example-annotation/

Comment: How does your code compile, I do not see getAllUsers() method in the ElasticSearchRepository ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the problem statement, I am able to find two problems and solution is below:

Please try this

1. Please try with in the class ElasticSearchRepository.java
   `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.elastic" })`
2. `@Component()` rename with `@Controller` in the MainController.java class

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the way you are using `MainController`, If your main controller is not initialized and provisioned by spring context i.e. you have created an instance of `MainController` using `new` keyword.

Secondly I do not see `getAllUsers()` method in the ElasticSearchRepository, Just wondering how does your code compile ?

Comment: I have posted wrong method findAllUsers . Its there now . Its my mistake